# Turning categorical data into numeric vectors

Tags: r, categorical-data

I am trying to convert a vector- "Years Experience" with a several thousand observations into a numeric value. The potential responses for "Years Experience"  are coded as "0 to 1", "1 to 2", "2 to 3" etc. all the way to "39 to 40".

I thought a simple `factor` command would provide a numeric vector. Consider the following example responses for years experience where I am looking for 1 to be associated with the "0 to 1" response:

```
YE<- c("8 to 9", "2 to 3", "1 to 2"...."39 to 40"
YE_adjusted<- as.numeric(factor(YE, c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7....40)
View(YE_adjusted)
```

We viewing `YE_adjusted` all I see is a vector of NA values. Whats the correct solution to get my desired output?

Comment: You cannot see a vector of null values, R does not support that. It supports (a) a `list` of `NULL`, and (b) a vector of `NA` (and I suspect you have this one). The second argument of `factor` is the levels to assign to it, and they typically start with the unique values within the character vector, not arbitrary numbers (you might have more in levels than in the data, but not the other way around). So if you replace `c(1,2,3,...,40)` with `unique(YE)`, it will work without error, but I don't know that this is what you want.

Comment: Perhaps you just need `as.integer(factor(YE))`?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to "bin" your data. Have you looked at `cut`?

Comment: hi @r2evans, you are complete correct, it returns a list of "Na" values. I tried the following on this example and got different results which aren't what I am looking for exactly. 

```data<- c("1 to 2", "7 to 8", "7 to 8", "0-1"...."36 to 37") 
#up to 40 years of experience values possible.

f_test<- as.numeric(factor(data, unique(data)))
f_test_2<- as.integer(factor(data))

View(f_test)
View(f_test_2)
```

Neither of these two lines returns what I am looking for, which would be a numeric vector of (2,8,8,1...37). 

In fact ```View f_test_2``` returns 2,38,38...

Comment: It's difficult to help, SudSampath, since I don't know what your real data looks like. I don't know if the "2, 8, 8, 1" should apply to ... idk. From the sounds of it, you are either doing a distributional test,  or... ok, you just accepted H1's answer. I'm glad you found something useful. :-)

Comment: Thank you for your help! I was actually trying to convert these string responses for years experience into a numeric form so I can build a Mincer equation to estimate salaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `mixedsort()` from the `gtools` package to set the factor levels before coercing to numeric.

```
library(gtools)

YE_adjusted<- as.numeric(factor(YE, levels = unique(mixedsort(YE))))
```

This should ensure that the factor levels are kept in a sensible order before conversion:

```
factor(YE, levels = unique(mixedsort(YE)))

[1] 8 to 9   2 to 3   1 to 2   39 to 40
Levels: 1 to 2 2 to 3 8 to 9 39 to 40
```

If you want to do it in base, then you could try the following. If your data follows the examples provided, it should work.

```
as.numeric(factor(as.numeric(sub("(\\d+).*", "\\1", YE))))
```

Comment: This was great! Thanks! Is there a way to use base R to solve this question though?